# Is it redundant to say "the plot of the story"?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I'm writing a paper about title cards and title sequences in movies and at one point I say

> These title cards were also used throughout silent films as they were essential to carrying *the plot of the story* by displaying dialogue and signifying changes in setting.

Is this redundant?

Comment: It's not redundant, but it is a little verbose.

Comment: _Of the story_ is redundant in the sense that it's not essential: you can remove it and the sentence will still mean the same thing and be perfectly understandable, since there's nothing else in the sentence that has a _plot_. But it's not redundant in the frequently interpreted sense that it is unnecessary and therefore pointless and must be pruned off. There's nothing with keeping it.

Comment: If I were you, I would get rid of it: it adds nothing, whether in terms of meaning or of rhetorical impact.